# Why do numbers with 17 and more digits turn EVEN automatically?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, numbers, rounding, precision

I'm testing a photo application for Facebook. I'm getting object IDs from the Facebook API, but I received some incorrect ones, which doesn't make sense - why would Facebook send wrong IDs?  I investigated a bit and found out that numbers with 17 and more digits are automatically turning into even numbers!

For example, let's say the ID I'm supposed to receive from Facebook is `12345678912345679`. In the debugger, I've noticed that Flash Player automatically turns it into `12345678912345678`. And I even tried to manually set it back to an odd number, but it keeps changing back to even.

Is there any way to stop Flash Player from rounding the numbers? BTW the variable is defined as `Object`, I receive it like that from Facebook.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is related to the implementation of data types:

- `int` is a 32-bit number, with an even distribution of positive and
  negative values, including 0.  So the maximum value is

  `(2^32 / 2 ) - 1 == 2,147,483,647`.
- `uint` is also a 32-bit number, but it doesn't have negative values.  So the
  maximum value is

  `2^32 - 1 == 4,294,967,295`.

When you use a numerical value greater than the maximum value of `int` or `uint`, it is automatically cast to `Number`. [From the Adobe Doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html):

> The Number data type is useful when you need to use floating-point
>   values. Flash runtimes handle int and uint data types more efficiently
>   than Number, but Number is useful in situations where the range of
>   values required exceeds the valid range of the int and uint data
>   types. The Number class can be used to represent integer values well
>   beyond the valid range of the int and uint data types. The Number data
>   type can use up to 53 bits to represent integer values, compared to
>   the 32 bits available to int and uint.

53 bits have a maximum value of:

`2^53 - 1 == 9,007,199,254,740,989` => 16 digits

So when you use any value greater than that, the inner workings of floating point numbers apply.

You can read about floating point numbers [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), but in short, for any floating point value, the first couple of bits are used to specify a multiplication factor, which determines the location of the point. This allows for a greater range of values than are actually possible to represent with the number of bits available - at the cost of reduced precision.

**When you have a value greater than the maximum possible integer value a Number could have, the least significant bit (the one representing 0 and 1) is cut off to allow for a more significant bit (the one representing 2^54) to exist => hence, you lose the odd numbers.**

There is a simple way to get around this: Keep all your IDs as Strings - they can have as many digits as your system has available bytes ;)  It's unlikely you're going to do any calculations with them, anyway.

By the way, if you had a value greater than `2^54-(1+2)`, your numbers would be rounded down to the next multiple of 4; if you had a value greater than `2^55-(1+2+4)`, they would be rounded down to the next multiple of 8, etc.

Comment: Great answer, Pirate. Just wanted to add that it's always a good idea to store ID's as a String, especially in languages with operator overloading, such as AS3, where "+" is used for addition but also for string concatenation. If you use the ID to construct instance names, for example, you could inadvertently be adding ID's instead of concatenating.
For example:
`var ID : Number = 1234567;
mc[ ID + 456 ].gotoAndPlay( 10 )`

Comment: thanks for the GREAT answer! . The problem is im getting the ids from facebook as object! , so they are already rounded when i recieve them. So how can i founf out if flash builder rounded it to a higher of smaller number. I mean if i got a number with "8" as the last digit, what was the digit before it was rounded, 7 or 9?

Comment: Flash Builder has nothing to do with it - it's a runtime issue. You should be able to make that object map to String instead of Number. Which API calls are you using?

Comment: Also, it's not actually rounded, and the value is always the next lower multiple of 2. The problem, though, is that you can't know if the value is correct in the first place.

Comment: Im using fql to query the photo table. "SELECT object_id FROM photo WHERE subject=me()". I dont clearly understand what is "next lower multiple of 2"?. In one case i had ,the real object id ended with "9" and I got 8 in FLASH BUILDER.

Comment: And your right i cant tell wheter the value is correct or no, so i actually make 2 calls, one with the object_id i got from the fql and one with object id after a fix. The problem is of course how should i fix it? +1 or -1, and another problem is that i can get wrong information in case there are two sequential object_ids. \:

Comment: You should be able to get `event.data.rawResult` on the FacebookEvent in your result handler. This can be used to get the unconverted XML data returned by Facebook.

Comment: Tried to find it with the debugger, but came up with nothing \: